# How to display a splash screen while making fragment transaction?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to display a splash screen with a spinner while making the transaction below. (It takes time to prepare)

```
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

At first, I try to model present an activity, and dismiss it when the transaction is over.
However, app crashes with "cannot perform this action after onsaveinstancestate".

How can I do this right?
Is there another way to display a splash image?

Comment: You should make that transaction go faster, there isn't a reason to be so slow that you'd need a splash screen(which you should avoid in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

You should add a view in front of '`fragment_container`' containing a spinner and set its visibility to `VISIBLE` before the transaction, and to `GONE` when your fragment has finished loading.

May be you will have to set this view as clickable to prevent the user from interacting with the view below.

Comment: How can I "add a view in front of 'fragment_container'"?

Comment: Can you send the xml of your view containing the one with id "fragment_container"?

Answer (score 0):

Error called "cannot perform this action after onsaveinstancestate" can be solved with

```
transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

instead of

```
transaction.commit();
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184653/commitallowingstateloss-in-fragment-activities) is an explanation.