# Illegal state exception in onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've got this code in a fragment:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
        if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri;
            if (resultData != null) {
                uri = resultData.getData();
                getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(new MyFragment(), TAG).commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

However there is crash with IllegalStateException. The activity can't create/restore transactions after onSaveInstanceState(). What is the correct method to start a fragment from another one in onActivityResult()?

Logcat:

```
03-17 18:55:37.372 26127 26127 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
03-17 18:55:37.372 26127 26127 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1434)
03-17 18:55:37.372 26127 26127 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1452)
03-17 18:55:37.372 26127 26127 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:708)
03-17 18:55:37.372 26127 26127 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:672)
03-17 18:55:37.372 26127 26127 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.xxxx.ttyy.ui.SettingsFragment.onActivityResult(Unknown Source)
03-17 18:55:37.372 26127 26127 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6956)
03-17 18:55:37.372 26127 26127 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4085)
03-17 18:55:37.372 26127 26127 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 9 more
03-17 18:55:37.377   878  3186 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.balda.intenttask/.ui.MainActivity
```

Comment: Can you add the logcat, please?

Comment: And did you try using `beginTransaction().replace` instead?

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't want to replace the fragment

Answer (score 0):

You can use [commitAllowingStateLoss](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commitAllowingStateLoss())

From the Documentation:

> Like `commit()` but allows the commit to be executed after an activity's
>   state is saved. This is dangerous because the commit can be lost if
>   the activity needs to later be restored from its state, so this should
>   only be used for cases where it is okay for the UI state to change
>   unexpectedly on the user.

try using this:

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(new MyFragment(), TAG).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: Depends...it works in my case...so i would not call it just a `workaround`..see the Answer [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184653/commitallowingstateloss-in-fragment-activities)