# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

While doing fragment transaction getting below error

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:666)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:639)
       at com.mahindra.testdrive.Fragments.ScheduleFragment.moveToBookingDetails(ScheduleFragment.java:1911)
       at com.mahindra.testdrive.Fragments.ScheduleFragment.access$900(ScheduleFragment.java:93)
       at com.mahindra.testdrive.Fragments.ScheduleFragment$5$1.onItemClick(ScheduleFragment.java:1520)
       at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:350)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1674)
       at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:4085)
       at android.widget.AbsListView$10.run(AbsListView.java:6573)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
```

Comment: Can you please post code of fragment transaction?

Comment: Fragment fragment = new TestdriveDetailsFrament();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        try
        {
            transaction.commit();
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e)
        {
            transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }

Comment: Don't do code dumps in the comment section. Make sure to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your question.

Comment: Replace `transaction.commit()` with `transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();`

Comment: ok thanks,will replace and check

Comment: transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss(); could not be the right solution, check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184653/commitallowingstateloss-in-fragment-activities